# What does the with-open macro do behind the scenes in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Visually, `with-open` looks similar to `let`. I know with-open is for a different purpose but I cannot find a clear answer as to what `with-open` is doing. And, what is the first argument in with-open?

The documentation says this:

> *"bindings => [name init ...]
> Evaluates body in a try expression with names bound to the values
> of the inits, and a finally clause that calls (.close name) on each
> name in reverse order."*

I do not understand this. I would really appreciate if someone explained what with-open actually does?

Comment: Is there something in particular which you don't understand about this sentence? It's hard to give an answer without just repeating what the documentation already says.

Comment: You can see what it *actually* does in the source code: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3831 Does that make it more clear? Have you seen the examples in the documentation?

Comment: There are two things I do not understand: first, what does it do. On the surface it looks like it does the same thing as let. Secondly, when should I use it? I see it used in many libraries and I do not undertand why. 

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what `let` does (I don't know Clojure), but does it call `.close` at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what does it do?

A macroexpanded example, with some formatting and after removing unnecessary explicit usages of `clojure.core/...`:

```
(macroexpand-1
  '(with-open [reader (some-fn-that-creates-a-reader)]
     (read-stuff reader)))
=>
(let [reader (some-fn-that-creates-a-reader)]
  (try
    ;; This `with-let` is just a no-op, like `(let [] ...)` - an artifact of the implementation.
    (with-open [] (read-stuff reader))
    (finally (. reader close))))
```

As you can see, it's exactly the same as `let`, but it wraps the body in a `try` form and closes the values provided in the binding vector in the `finally` form.

> when should I use it?

When you need for something to be closed at the end, regardless of whether the code in the body was successful or not.

It's a common pattern for reading/writing files with an explicit reader/writer or for using other IO that needs to be opened and closed explicitly.

Comment: This really explains why with-open is used in many database examples. Thank you for explaining this. Super useful!

Why does `finally` close the the file/connection at the end?

Comment: @Vinn That's the entire purpose of the macro: to close the file when the "block" is exited.